# Is there a specific name for a set with a defined binary operation, that is not a group?

Tags: group-theory, notation, terminology, binary-operations

Is there a specific name for a set with a defined binary operation, that is not a group? e.g.:

({1, 2, 3, 6}, +).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A binary operation is a map $\circ : A \times A \to A$, which you don't actually have since $1 + 3$ is outside your set.

---

However, the term for a set equipped with a binary operation is a [magma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra)).

Comment: I see, so if the closure axiom fails then the operation is not **defined** on the set but the set is rather **equipped** with it?   But from the link you gave, it say a magma requires the operation to be closed in the set.  So my example can't be called a magma then?

Comment: Right, your example is not a magma. If you don't have closure, then it's not proper to refer to your thing as having a binary operation.

Comment: I see, I guess, it's just not interesting enough to deserve a name :)  Thanks